# Don Quixote is magically time warped into the modern era

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I have been searching for a science fiction short story that I found a few years ago. It involved Don Quixote magically being time warped into the modern era.  He finds a Mexican-American soldier and the two begin a comical journey together.

The short story was written in the early to mid 90's and I found it in a Science Fiction Anthology. I remember that it was the funniest science fiction short story that I have ever read and I would love to be able to read it again.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for "[Daddy's World](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91917)" by Walter Jon Williams, originally published in "Not of Women Born" but you're much more likely to have seen it collected in "The Year's Best Science Fiction: Seventeenth Annual Collection"

[image]

In it, *a child's perfect world is interrupted when he learns his body died and his brain scan is just a computer program ... and his family is using an AI interface to pretend everything is normal.*

You can find a preview of the story [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791825/9781625791825___1.htm)

Comment: While that story features Don Quixote as a virtual Spanish teacher, that is only a minor sideplot, and he does not go adventuring with a Mexican soldier, so I don't think that story fits. Good story though.

Comment: @hugorune -alas, since the OP has failed to comment, we may never know. The time frame fits, it's a comedy (of sorts) and it's been heavily anthologised over the years.